# how to do a status check on a checkbox?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

when a click event occurs on a checkbox (in a view), i want this catched with jquery and depending on the checked or unchecked status, sent a post to a controller to change a database field. the row-id should also be catched with jquery, what i try to do with the data-attribute. I found a possible manner, but it doesn't work. Nothing happens on a click.

Can someone help me out please. Thanks.

view:

```
 foreach (var item in Model.Messages)
        {
            <tr>
             <td>@Html.CheckBox("check", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class",   
                 "myCheckboxes" }, { "data-identity", item.ID } })
            </td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.message)
            </td> 
           </tr>
        }
```

jquery:

```
$('.myCheckboxes').click(function () {
            var my_id = $(this).attr('data-identity');
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                //code...
            }
            else {
                //code...
            }  
        });
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? And use data('identity') instead of attr('data-identity')

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code to catch a selected checkbox. I'm not sure what you mean with the data-attribute.

```
    // Subscribe to change events
        $(document).on('change', '.myCheckboxes', function(){
        var my_id = $(this).attr('data-identity');
                    // If the checkbox is checked
                    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                        //code...
                    }
                    else {
                        //code...
                    }  
         });
```

Comment: I've modified my code, could you try this out? Did you also try adding document.ready before the click/change event?

Comment: for data, it should be : var my_id = $(this).data('identity');

Comment: could it be because the checkboxes were added dynamically?

Comment: @user3544570 Yes, once you load data with ajax then the content changes and you can't use the "normal" functions to get data. You will need to use the $(document).on method. (That's what i use)